# Connecting each column with each other with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: c++, opengl

I've created these triangles using triangle strip. I was wondering if there's a better way to connect the triangles to each other (first picture). For now I just created the triangles based on the previous columns verticies (second picture). So is there a better way so I dont have to calculate all the previous vertices?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to avoid recalculating/storing some previous vertices is to use an index buffer

https://www.learnopengles.com/tag/triangle-strips/